# Limit of a function

Tags: calculus, limits

Please help me with this question.

Let $f(x) =x^2 +x$. Show that $f(x) -f(2) = (x+3)(x-2)$.

Hence, find

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 2} \frac{f(x) - f(2)}{x -2}.$$

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 2} x+3=5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that

$$f(2)= (2)^2 + 2 = 6.$$

Now,

$$f(x) - f(2) = x^2 + x - 6 = (x+3)(x-2).$$

We can use this equality to evaluate the limit,

$$\require{cancel} \lim \limits_{x \to 2} \frac{f(x) - f(2)}{x - 2} =\lim \limits_{x \to 2} \frac{(x+3)(x-2)}{x-2} = \lim \limits_{x \to 2} \frac{(x+3) \cancel{(x-2)}}{\cancel{x-2}} = \lim \limits_{x \to 2} \left( x+ 3\right) = 2 + 3 = 5.$$